# Making Google Custom Search display results on a new tab

Tags: html, css, uisearchbar, google-search, google-search-api

I am developing [a website](http://widgetsinabottle.com/widget/demo/effect.html#.UBK6qmEe5K3) which has custom Google search bar embedded into it. My client wants a functionality that when a user searches something into that search box, a new page should open where he should be shown the result of his search. The current Google search bar displays the result just below it. Is there any way I can change to display the results in a new tab? Please help out. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the new Google Custom Search Widget. It provides a simple parameter to open the searched item in a new window. The method you are using is deprecated.

```
<gcse:searchbox-only resultsUrl="http://www.example.com" newWindow="true" queryParameterName="search">
```

For more information visit [this](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/widgets#overview).